# EJB loses @MappedSuperclass attribute

Tags: ejb, jax-ws, java-ee-8

I've got WebService, which getting date over EJB, but in the result I'm missing attibute which is in mapped superclass

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REASON", schema = "XXX")
@NamedQueries({
})
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class Reason extends SSEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7071943771305035766L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "REASON_ID")
    private Long reasonId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "INTERNAL_ID")
    private Long internalId;   
 
}
```

mapped superclass

```
@MappedSuperclass
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public abstract class SSEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Version
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    @Setter
    @Getter(onMethod=@__({@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlTimestampAdapter.class)}))
    private Timestamp updateTimestamp;

}
```

I have web service method that lists reasons, but if I use EJB I don't get update timestamp attribute

```
@WebService(name = "IIntegrationInboundRemoteWSSEI", targetNamespace = "http://XXX.WebServices")
public interface WebService {

    @WebMethod
    List<Reason> listReasonsAllEJB() throws Exception;

    @WebMethod
    List<Reason> listReasonsAll() throws Exception;    
}
```

web service implementation

```
@Stateless
@WebService(
        serviceName = "RemoteWebService",
        targetNamespace = "http://XXX.WebServices",
        endpointInterface = "com.azs.ws.WebService",
        portName = "RemoteWebServicePort"
)
public class WebServiceImpl implements WebService {

    @EJB(beanName = "WsEJBImpl")
    private WsEJB bean;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Reason> listReasonsAllEJB() throws Exception {
        return bean.listRejectionReasonsAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Reason> listReasonsAll() throws Exception {
        return entityManager
                .createNamedQuery("listReasons", Reason.class)
                .setParameter("date", new Date())
                .getResultList();
    }

}
```

EJB is as follows

```
@Remote
public interface WsEJB {

    List<Reason> listReasonsAll() throws Exception;    

}
```

EJB implementation

```
@Stateless
@Remote(WsEJB.class)
public class WsEJBImpl implements WsEJB {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Reason> listReasonsAll() throws Exception {
        return entityManager
                .createNamedQuery("listReasons", Reason.class)
                .setParameter("date", new Date())
                .getResultList();
    }

}
```

as You can see methods *listReasonsAllEJB()* and *listReasonsAll()* do the same

when I test these methods with SoapUI I get
[image: I've lost updateTimestamp attribute]

[image: updateTimestamp attribute exists]

when using EJB I'm losing updateTimestamp attribute, what I'm missing?..

Answer (score 0):

my abstarct entity class has to be serialized

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class SSEntity implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5741595897057015891L;
    
        @NotNull
        @Version
        @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
        @Setter
        @Getter(onMethod=@__({@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlTimestampAdapter.class)}))
        private Timestamp updateTimestamp;
    
    }
```